# I have react-native-gesture-handler and other modules outside of app.. is it right?

Tags: react-native, android-studio

can you see my error.. please?? i wanna cry..

I donwloaded npm install @react-navigation and I got an error with react-native-gesture-handler, so downloaded npm install native-gesture-handler..
But some modules(see, that react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-safe-are-context..) are outside of app component, so I guess I downloaded react-native-gesture-handler in a wrong way..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've done anything wrong, it's just that you have your whole project directory open in android studio, and those packages rely on native code so they have some android code and will show up beside your project.

You can open Project directory instead of Android at the top left in android studio if you wanna focus on your project files only.

Comment: It was my fault.. I should have enter to my project using 'cd blahblah~~' thank you !!
I just deleted my all codes using sourcetree, and I figured out my problems~!!